# Why do you say "to place a call"?

Tags: etymology

I know *to make a call* and this makes sense to me. But recently I read in an article:

> [...] if you are actually placing calls.

I wonder about the verb *to place*. NGram Viewer shows that this phrase is in use for about 100 years now. Where does it come from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first guess is "place a call" originated from when the operator would physically have to plug the wires on a switchboard to make a call.

From [HowStuffWorks](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/question354.htm):

> Think back to a time when a human being worked in a town's central office. The phone company would build the central office in the middle of town, and then run a pair of copper wires to every home (see How Telephones Work for details on the wiring). The operator -- let's call her Mabel -- would work in the central office. Mabel would sit in front of a switchboard, and on this switchboard would be a collection of sockets -- one socket for each of the phones in town. When you wanted to place a call:
>
> - You would pick up your phone.
> - A light above your phone's socket would turn on.
> - Mabel would plug a jack into your socket and ask you who you would like to talk to.
> - Mabel would then plug her jack into the receiving party's socket, send a ring signal down the line, and talk to the person who answered.
> - Mabel would then plug in a wire between your jack and the receiving party's jack to connect the two of you together.
> - When she saw the lights go out above your jacks, Mabel would remove the wire connecting the two sockets.

*Electrical review, Volume 45* from [1904](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=uFNoT8blGOGm4gTj3KG4CQ&id=1IwfAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22place%20a%20call%22%20OR%20%22place%20the%20call%22%20OR%20%22place%20your%20call%22%20OR%20%22place%20my%20call%22%20telephone&q=%22place%20a%20call%22#search_anchor) talks of placing a call in front of an operator. This corresponds with the switchboard lights turning on in front of Mabel:

> Wires should be led from this trunk plug to a desk located outside of the operating room, and having facilities for testing the called line after the plug is inserted, and listening upon it without closing it, so as to **place a call before the operator** if it is not in use.

So when the caller picks up the phone, they are placing something in front of an operator (some indicating lights) to indicate you wish to make a call. The operator then places some wires in plugs to initiate the call. This gives us at least two senses of things being placed.

Comment: +1. In some parts of the world, you still contact the operator to *place an international call*, and the operator gives you a time when it will actually go through.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I wonder if it's a holdover from days when callers needed operator assistance to place a call.

Because callers needed help calling a *place*, the language *place a call* would naturally evolve. If I picked up the phone, and my friendly neighborhood operator was on the other end, "*I'd like to you to help me place a call*" seems like a perfectly natural thing to say, rather than "*I"d like you to help me call a place*."  (That's just a theory, but the blue line on the graph would seem to support it, as it coincides with the spread of the telephone into rural areas.)

As to why *make a call* is so much more widely used in the Ngram, not all references to *make a call* revolve around a telephone.  A referee can *make a call* on the field.  Because *make a call* is an idiom for *make a decision*, a board of directors can *make a call* about a new stock option.

Comment: And a doctor can make a house call, so it's certainly not inconceivable that to *make a call* referred (or still refers) to visiting someone in some dialects.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when we used to go up to the post office to ring up . we did not have a house phone. We went to the telephonist booth, and asked if we could 
 Place a trunk call (long distance). There were others waiting there were two telephone boxes.Then the telephonist would call out to us to go to  telephone box 1 or 2 to take our call. This was during WW11.